# Where to find a list of rectangle data to test intersections

Tags: collision, overlap

Is there a list somewhere containing pairs of test (positions and dimensions of) rectangles and whether they are overlapping?

Even better if they cover every case of rectangle-rectangle intersections (completely inside, just corner, length of one inside width of another, etc).